# Azure publish from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012

When I publish my WebRole from VIsual Studio 2012 I get alwais this error.

The HTTP request to has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I have to try several times to publish. Any idea?

Comment: Have you perhaps deleted the cloud service that the web role used to run under? Check the publish settings and ensure the cloud service name doesn't have an error in the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to your internet connection. 
Did you check the "tracert" for the host "management.core.windows.net"? It will tell you the route taken to the destination.

Also, you can always try deploying the package manually. In fact, from my experience deploying manually is faster than that from visual studio.

Comment: I have no prolem with internet connection. Manually it works great. Very strange behaviour from Visual Studio.